# Cpp function call from header file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header-files

There is two files one is .cpp file another is .h file , header file

This class is present in .h file

```
class DecodeTheCode
{
public:
char* decodeCode(char* encodedString);
};
```

now software which i am using  asks

•Implement your logic in function char* decodeCode(char* encodedString)

but i have declared

```
const char* decodeCode(const char* encodedString)
{
const char*  decodedString = "";
const char* a = encodedString;
char store[10000];

for(int j=0;j<strlen(a);j++)
{
    if (isdigit(a[j]) || a[j] == '#')
        continue;
    else return "";
}
int i = 0,k=0;
while (i < strlen(a))
{
    if (a[i] == '#') {i++; continue;}
    else if(a[i] == a[i+1] && a[i+1] == a[i+2] && a[i+2] == a[i+3])
    {
        store[k++] = four(a[i]);
        i += 4;
    }
    else if (a[i] == a[i+1] && a[i+1] == a[i+2])
    {
        store[k++] = three(a[i]);
        i += 3;
    }
    else if (a[i] == a[i+1])
    {
        store[k++] = two(a[i]);
        i += 2;
    }
    else
    {
        store[k++] = one(a[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
store[k]='\0';
decodedString=store;              // line number 103
return  decodedString;
```

}

in .cpp file

now the software is showing

```
Error(s) encountered:
C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Loca/Temp/cco5baaa.o(.text+0x18f):TestDecodeTheCode.cpp:undefined reference to
DecodeTheCode::decodeCode(char*)'
C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/cco5baaa.o(.text+0x1a4):TestDecodeTheCode.cpp: undefined reference to `DecodeTheCode::decodeCode(char*)'
C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/cco5baaa.o(.text+0x24d):TestDecodeTheCode.cpp: undefined reference to `DecodeTheCode::decodeCode(char*)'
C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/cco5baaa.o(.text+0x262):TestDecodeTheCode.cpp: undefined reference to `DecodeTheCode::decodeCode(char*)'
C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/cco5baaa.o(.text+0x30b):TestDecodeTheCode.cpp: undefined reference to `DecodeTheCode::decodeCode(char*)'
C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/cco5baaa.o(.text+0x320):TestDecodeTheCode.cpp: more undefined references to `DecodeTheCode::decodeCode(char*)' follow
```

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

```
/decodethecode/decodethecode.c: In function `char* decodeCode(const char*)':
/decodethecode/decodethecode.c:103: error: invalid conversion from `const char*' to `char*'
```

i am using 
    const char* decodeCode(const char* encodedString)
in place of 
    char* decodeCode(char* encodedString)
because otherwise i gets deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’

Have you any idea how I could fix it? If so, please write it down clearly (I am newbie...).

Answer (score 6):

You need to fully qualify the definition and change the types in the declaration to match the definition types. In the `.cpp` file this just defines a free function:

```
const char* decodeCode(const char* encodedString)
{
}
```

and is not associated with the member function declaration. To fully qualify:

```
const char* DecodeTheCode::decodeCode(const char* encodedString)
{
}
```

Change the types in the declaration of `decodeCode()` also.

More importantly, you are returning a pointer to a local variable named `store`. This will go out of scope and leave the caller with a dangling pointer. To return a `char*` you need to dynamically allocate memory using `new char[size]` and caller must remember to `delete[]` the returned data. The return type would not need to change to `const char*` if returning dynamically allocated memory. But you must be consistent, specifically don't on occassion return a string literal, like `""`, and on another return dynamically allocated memory otherwise the caller will be attempting to `delete[]` memory it should not.

If possible, use `std::string` instead of `char*`. It removes the burden of managing dynamically allocated memory from you.

Comment: can you please tell me how should i pass store[] into decodedString; i am using store[] just to make it a type of string so that i can pass it using return function.

Comment: @user1590595, the simplest way to do this would to `return std::string(store);` and change the return type to `std::string`. Is this permitted?

Comment: no i can't change the .h file.and the return type has to be the same. can you figure out something else ?

Comment: @user1590595, you will need to use `new[]`. First determine size of array required `size_t size = strlen(store) + 1`, the allocate `char* result = new char[size];` then copy into `result`. There are several ways to copy, one being `memcpy(result, store, size);` and then `return result;`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the function declaration from `const char* decodeCode(const char* encodedString) {` to `const char* DecodeTheCode::decodeCode(const char* encodedString) {`.  The `DecodeTheCode::` part tells the compiler that the 'decodeCode()' function is a part of the 'DecodeTheCode' class, and not a part of some other class or even a global.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`const char* decodeCode(const char* encodedString)`

to look this way:

```
char* DecodeTheCode::decodeCode(char* encodedString)
```

This way it is a class method definition, not just a new function declaration and definition as in your new code.

The deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ comes from your method invocation, I believe, not from the way you declare it. You can show how you use this method so I would be sure how to solve this problem.